# Using an all semaphore program instead of mutex and cond_t

Tags: c, pthreads, conditional-statements, mutex, semaphore

I am a beginner at C and I was just studying more in a book I picked up. I got to mutex locks and conditional variables and stuff like that. I saw an exercise in the book that said to switch a program that had mutex locks and conditional to a program that used semaphores instead to achieve the same results. I'm currently stuck because when I run the code, I believe I have the situation of being "deadlocked" and nothing happens after. I'm not sure what's wrong but any help would be appreciated. This is what I have now.

```
int main(){
  pthread_t pid;
  pthread_t cid;

  sem_init(&empty, 1, BUFSIZE);
  sem_init(&full, 1, BUFSIZE);

  randData =  (unsigned int) time(NULL);

  printf("Creating threads\n\n");

  pthread_create(&pid, NULL, produce, ids);
  pthread_create(&cid, NULL, consume, ids);  
  pthread_join(pid, NULL);
  pthread_join(cid, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify -- should there be multiple producers and consumers in the semaphore version? It looks like you had several of each in your condition variable output, but I only see you creating one of each in the new code.

Comment: There are 2 in produce. 1 for pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal
There are 2 in consume, same as produce

sorry about that. where should I be creating more?

Answer (score 0):

In code for producer, below, mutex_wait() is for same "mutex" twice which can lock while post() is only once in consumer.

```
sem_wait(&empty);
sem_wait(&mutex);  <---
while ( isFull() ){
  printf("%*sProducer %d waits\n", id*5, "", id);
}

enter(value);
printf("%*sProducer %d stores %d    ", id*5, "", id, value);
print();
printf("\n");

sem_wait(&mutex);  <---
sem_post(&full);
```

Few ideas to get it good in shape is When there is wait for empty or full, just add one check rather than loop and do mutex wait() in producer and from consumer post() it when it is empty or not full.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your solution is pretty close, but you still have some of the condition/wait stuff leftover that you shouldn't need. For example, once a thread take the appropriate semaphore, it knows it can proceed.

Check me on this code -- there may be some issues, but here's what I'd recommend (it's pseudo C)

```
void* produce(void* arg)
{ 
  // Wait for any item to be present in queue
  sem_wait(&isNotFullSem);

  // Take "mutex" to protect buffer
  sem_wait(&mutex);

  // Enqueue new value
  enter(value);

  // Release mutex
  sem_post(&mutex);

  // Signal that buffer is not empty
  //  (probably not the best name, but similar to condition)
  sem_post(&isNotEmptySem);
}

void* consume(void* arg)
{
  // Wait for empty space to be present in queue
  sem_wait(&isNotEmptySem);

  // Take "mutex" to protect buffer
  sem_wait(&mutex);

  // Enqueue new value
  value = leave();

  // Release mutex
  sem_post(&mutex);

  // Signal that buffer is not full
  sem_post(&isNotFullSem);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but I keep on getting a deadlock for some reason

Comment: @JamesWilliams Hmm, I can't see how the code I have above would result in a deadlock. Can you post your updates to your question so I can take a look? Does the deadlock occur only when the program should terminate? You need some handling for that case (i.e. set exit = 1 and post isNotFull and isNotEmpty to make threads return).

Comment: put my update using your psuedocode as an answer, thanks